# function with multiple outputs in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have problem that I could not figured out yet. In this problem I want to assemble chocolates in ordered way. To do this I have function called chocolate() and seven inputs which are

1. final weight (27)
2. number of smaller chocolates (4)
3. weight of smaller chocolates (2)
4. number of medium chocolates (4)
5. weight of medium chocolates (5)
6. number of large chocolates (3)
7. weight of large chocolates (8)

The problem wants from me to use as much as large chocolate then medium them small ones and finally return to (number of final small chocolates in final, number of  medium chocolates in final, number of large chocolates in final). Actually it looks easy but I am not sure about how can I use functions with multiple inputs and then return to multiple outputs. IF you can help me about how can I start I would be very glad and continue to write a proper code, I hope.

Here some example

```
input: 27 4 2 4 5 3 8 
output: 3 1 2
```

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem.  For example, you say you have seven inputs are these inputs in a dictionary, a list, or separate variable.  You say you want to generate multiple outputs what is the form of the output" Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I imagined that your goal is packing the chocolates, starting with the big ones first and trying to reach the target weight if possible.

The below returns the packed choc sizes and also the packed weight, as it may not always be possible to exactly match the target weight.

As you may know, this is a known problem called 'bin packing' with better solutions than the 'first-fit decreasing' approach below (which assumes only one bin).

```
def chocolates(final_weight, num_small_choc, w_small_choc, num_medium_choc, w_medium_choc, num_big_choc, w_big_choc):
    packed_weight = 0

    # Try to pack chocolates if they are not too big
    def pack_choc(packed_weight, num_choc, w_choc):
        while num_choc > 0:
            if packed_weight + w_choc <= final_weight:
                packed_weight += w_choc
                num_choc -= 1
            else:
                break
        return packed_weight, num_choc

    packed_weight, remaining_big_choc = pack_choc(packed_weight, num_big_choc, w_big_choc)
    packed_weight, remaining_medium_choc = pack_choc(packed_weight, num_medium_choc, w_medium_choc)
    packed_weight, remaining_small_choc = pack_choc(packed_weight, num_small_choc, w_small_choc)

    return num_small_choc - remaining_small_choc, num_medium_choc - remaining_medium_choc, num_big_choc - remaining_big_choc, packed_weight
    
>>> chocolates(27, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8)
... (1, 0, 3, 26)
```